# Traits NotImplemented Error

Tags: python, traitsui

I am using Anaconda Python and installed the traits api and traits ui using conda. I am on win 7. When I try to run simple hello world type scripts, I get an error saying

File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\traits\has_traits.py", line 2172, in configure_traits
    kind, handler, id, scrollable, args )
  File "C:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\traitsui\toolkit.py", line 291, in view_application
    raise NotImplementedError
NotImplementedError

Is this a anaconda specific traits error or something i am missing completely?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem recently.  Traits depends on qt.  So, install it by

```
conda install pyqt=4.11.4
```

Then add the following lines to the top of the python script

```
from traits.etsconfig.api import ETSConfig
ETSConfig.toolkit = 'qt4'
```

If you want to use wx, then install it and change 'qt4' to 'wx'.

Hope that helps.